# Maximum length of SIP via-branch parameter

Tags: sip

What is the maximum length of SIP via-branch parameter without magic cookie(=z9hG4bK). I need to get a maximum count of characters for my implementation. 
I tried to look for maximal length of branch parameter in [RFC3261](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3261.txt) and [RFC2543](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2543.txt), but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

The BNF definition for the via branch parameter is shown in [RFC3261](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261#page-232):

```
via-branch        =  "branch" EQUAL token
```

Token has no maximum length defined so there is no maximum length for this parameter.

[Paragraph 8.1.1.7](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261#section-8.1.1.7) states:

> The branch parameter value MUST be unique across space and time for
> all requests sent by the UA. [...] The branch ID inserted by an element compliant with this
> specification MUST always begin with the characters "z9hG4bK". [...] Beyond this requirement,
> the precise format of the branch token is implementation-defined.

To comply with the 'unique' requirement an implementation could opt to use a GUID (see [What is the string length of a GUID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968175/what-is-the-string-length-of-a-guid)), prefixed with "z9hG4bK". If you take this as max length you're pretty safe, but there is always a chance that an implementation uses another (longer) format.