# How can I get child path from registry via comand line (batch file)

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I have the registry path in a variable **%A%**. And I want to get the child name of that registry path and to execute the below command

```
MSIEXEC.EXE /qb /L* "%LOGDIR%\myuninstaller.log" /x{GUID}
```

Example:

```
SET %A%="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{C43A01F0-D4DB-4CA3-9DF6-7DF629BBCCD4}"
```

How can I get exactly this string `"{C43A01F0-D4DB-4CA3-9DF6-7DF629BBCCD4}"` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims={" %%# in ("%A%") do set "guid={%%#"
```

if the length is fixed ([it should be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968175/what-is-the-string-length-of-a-guid)) you can use substring syntax:

```
set "guid=%A:~-38%"
```