# What format does Elasticsearch use for its ids?

Tags: .net, elasticsearch

Elastic search ids that are generated by the system look like this.

```
"_id": "AU9HiR3lEVul15o3bNYl"
```

What format is that? Also does anyone know of a library to generate ids like that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Before v1.4.0 elasticsearch was using UUID-based ids. These ids were Base64 encoded version of a Version 4.0-compatible UUID as defined by [RFC4122](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt). In order to encode the ids an URL-safe Base64 encoding was used (see section 4 of [RFC3548](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3548.html)) and the last two "=" signs were removed (because Base64 encoding of 16 bytes would always generate two "=" at the end).

Unfortunately, completely random ids were less then ideal from [performance perspective](http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2014/05/choosing-fast-unique-identifier-uuid.html). So, starting with version 1.4.0 elasticsearch switched to time-based ids. The new id format is essentially a version of [flake ids](http://www.boundary.com/blog/2012/01/flake-a-decentralized-k-ordered-unique-id-generator-in-erlang/) except it is using 6 (not 8) bytes for timestamp and 3 (not 2) bytes for the sequence number.

The id in the question `AU9HiR3lEVul15o3bNYl` looks like a time-base id that was generated somewhere in the middle of Aug 2015.

Comment: External link under "flake ids" is long gone, but archived: http://web.archive.org/web/20141124212354/http://www.boundary.com/blog/2012/01/flake-a-decentralized-k-ordered-unique-id-generator-in-erlang/

Answer (score 1):

Autogenerated IDs are 22 character long, URL-safe, Base64-encoded string universally unique identifiers, or UUIDs, although it looks like your ID is 20 characters.

Some more .NET info here I think, looks like Guid.NewGuid will work.
[What is the string length of a GUID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/968175/what-is-the-string-length-of-a-guid)

Comment: I thought that format looked familiar but could not place it.

Comment: I see they chopped off the last 2 '==' to save space. Apparently when guids are turned into base64 it always adds 2 '==' to the end. http://madskristensen.net/post/A-shorter-and-URL-friendly-GUID